# What HTTP code i shuld return if nothing added to db in post method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, web, httpresponse

I have a post method that add an object to db. But what I should return if nothing added? I need to handle it in ajax request.

Comment: Why was nothing added?

Comment: Here is the complete list of status codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @Ryan, I don't know. Maybe lose connection or something.

Comment: @SashaPleshakov: What connection? If you mean the server’s database connection or something, that’s a server error and should be a 500.

Comment: @Ryan, db connection

Comment: Okay, so that would be a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Or maybe _502 (Bad Gateway)_

Answer (score 1):

A status 500 (server error) would make most sense to me.

- 200 success
- 300 rediret
- 400 client error (me)
- 500 server error (you)

You didn't add the object I posted to you, into the db, so you return 500. That way I can catch the error.

Edited to explain the status codes a bit better:

1. Don't return 200 unless there was a success with the post. You never wanna return 200 with message "didn't work"
2. If I'm sending you a wrong object/information to save you should send 400
3. If the connection on your end is lost or there's a problem with the insert statement a 500 would probably suit best.

And further: You can always send detailed messages with your status codes. But depending on the users using this service be careful not to expose/send information like sql errors.

Comment: 500: _A generic error message, given when an **unexpected condition** was encountered and **no more specific** message is suitable._ I don't think so

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from sending a 500 with a specific message. It's much better to actually return an error when there's something wrong so that I can catch instead of giving a success with "didn't work"

Also the poster gave an example of lost connection, which is a 503.

Comment: Yes,  _But what I should return if nothing added_ as the OP wrote - That's not necessarily mean an internal error happened

Comment: The poster gave an example of lost connection, which would probably fall under 503.
If there was an error with the insert on his end a 500 error would also be the best response.

Comment: I'm still not convinced but I'll remove my downvote because the question lacks important information so your opinion is as good as my

Comment: And now they commented _"I don't know. Maybe lose connection or something"_ so I'll even upvote your answer

Comment: Thank you and agreed there's some missing information to fully answer the question. I updated my answer to cover more scenarios. Thank you for you points.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is your use case you can:

**The new object violates conditions - either it already exists (unique constraint) or some other validations**

-> Then return `422 Unprocessable Entity` alongside with some error message in the body.

**You are doing server side deduplication - you want to gracefully send new objects and not care about duplications on client side**

-> Either pretend everything is OK, ie `201 Created` and return the original existing object as response. Or distinct between the states with `201 Created` for newly recorded object and `303 See other` with the original record as URL or just `204 No content`

**There is unexpected error on the server side during saving something that was expected to be recorded**

-> `500 Server Error`

Answer (score 0):

If the reason is bad data from the client in some form, you should use a status in the 400-range, most likely 422.
If the reason is due to some error on the backend you should use one in the 500-range. There are many different status codes to use. You should read up on them and use the one(s) that apply to your scenario.

[This is a good resource on HTTP statuses](https://httpstatuses.com).

Answer (score -1):

you should use **204** status code (204 ==> No Content)

Comment: Only if it was intentional not to add any data and not due to an error. Also, 204 means nothing is returned to the client and doesn't necessarily mean nothing was added to the database.

Comment: don't you just need to identify this particular case in JS ?? you cas set the response header that you want and you should explain more your problem